# Tag Wiki says I created the Tag in a Suggested Edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

[instant-self-answer](/questions/tagged/instant-self-answer) was created a couple days ago. Another user suggested a body of information for the wiki, and then they suggested an excerpt that was rejected.

Since then, I suggested another excerpt that was accepted. However this seems to make the suggested edit think that I created the tag. See the edit [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7107). Notice that it has me as the creator, but it's not attributing the current excerpt to me because it has blank space, indicating the original state of the excerpt.

I may be just reading it wrong, but this implies that I was the original creator? It's perhaps because the original creator was Community, but it's still inaccurate and odd.

Comment: No worries, only the excerpt looks up to you: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7106 Anyway, might it be the first time you created a tag-excerpt on meta?